# What is cisco meraki doing as referral in your analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Looking at the referrals of my website I noticed the second highest source is n213.network-auth.com which comes from the Cisco Meraki cloud management platform. I am puzzled to why it is in there and what it exactly means.

As far as I understand, this site contains a link to mine and it comes from the path /splash/. Furthermore the behaviour is strange: bounce 95% and 96% is targetting my landing page. A 100% would suggest there is software behind the visits, a not perfect score IMHO suggests humans.

Is this a ghostspam gone wrong attempt? A byproduct of a probing?

Comment: Just a guess:  Somebody tries to use your site but the request is getting intercepted and a network login is showing first.   When the user logs into the network they are then redirected to your site.